# Case When without Empty and Duplicated values

Tags: sql, db2

I need to do something like this in sql.
For example :

```
CASE city
   WHEN ["",""] THEN '[]', //if there is no city i must return '[]'
   WHEN ["Paris",""] THEN '["Paris"]' // i just have to return [ "Paris"] instead of ["Paris",""]
   WHEN ["Paris","Paris"]  THEN '["Paris"]' // without duplicated values
   ELSE 'other'
END
```

How can I do this please ?

Thank's for your help

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: What is the  type of city?

Comment: The type of city is Varchar(100)

Comment: You are trying to compare one value -- `city` -- with an `ARRAY` of values. It will never match.

Comment: Can you give an example of a value for city and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
CASE
   WHEN city = ''                  THEN '[]'       -- if there is no city i must return '[]'
   WHEN city = '["Paris",""]'      THEN '["Paris"]' -- i just have to return [ "Paris"] instead of ["Paris",""]
   WHEN city = '["Paris","Paris"]' THEN '["Paris"]' --// without duplicated values
   ELSE 'other'
END
```